# why doesn't text box align inline with submit button

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-ui

In my wordpress web site, I have used bbpress plugin. Following code is the reponsible to render search box and submit button.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="bbp-search-form" action="<?php bbp_search_url(); ?>">
    <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text hidden" for="bbp_search"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'bbpress' ); ?></label>
        <input placeholder="Search <?php the_title(); ?> Topics" tabindex="<?php bbp_tab_index(); ?>" type="text"  style="width:400px;height:20px;"value="<?php echo esc_attr( bbp_get_search_terms() ); ?>" name="bbp_search" id="bbp_search"  />
        <?php if( $forum_id ): ?>
        <input class="button" type="hidden" name="bbp_search_forum_id" value="<?php echo $forum_id; ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <input tabindex="<?php bbp_tab_index(); ?>" class="button" type="submit" id="bbp_search_submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'bbpress' ); ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

But the problem is when it render in IE , search box and button is not align properly.

see below screen shot.

[image: search box and button]

However, in localhost it is ok with IE webbrowser also. Problem is when I put it to the remote server. I found that the remote server is slight old version while local has the latest version.

Apart from this I use jquery UI to render the button styles.Where is the problem? do I need to upgrade the server?

Comment: Ah, not too sure then - on earlier versions of IE you had to add `zoom:1` to the parent container if you had rendering issues.  Never come across it for IE10

Comment: does it cause loading external css? I have used http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css for Jquery ui. I haven't saved it on the file system